# Kibana Visualize Table: Composite aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

This is the data I have in elasticsearch and I have to visualize the data as shown in step 2. Basically first I want to take the sum of the cost by grouping on `session` and `media` and then I want to take the average of the sum of the cost by `media`.

```
session  page   media      cost
a        1      facebook   12
b        1      twitter    6   
b        2      twitter    12
a        2      facebook   11
b        3      facebook   8
a        3      twitter    10
```

Step 1: Group By session, media and then take sum

```
session media      sum_of_cost
a       facebook   23
a       twitter    10
b       facebook   8
b       twitter    18
```

Step 2: Take average of the sum_of_cost by media

```
media       avg_sum_of_cost
facebook    15.5
twitter     14
```

How can I achieve this with pipeline aggregation for Kibana visualization particularly as table.